# Product import : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file for products. When clicked on "**check data**" button, it says "*File is valid! To start import process press 'Import' button* "

but when I click on the **import button**, I get the following error:

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row**

[image]

Here is the [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0PSOdsXhLE1NFVILUQyUHl6Q1E/view) to my csv file.

Comment: Please refer : http://www.createhosting.co.nz/support/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=70 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/30895585/3894567

Comment: @SanchitGupta : yes there were some special characters in my CSV  and i found it using regular expression as mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35023497/5820064)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by **Sanchit Gupta** in comment, the [SECOND_LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30895585/3894567) :

It solved my issue, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35023497/5820064) is the answer that helped me.